# downloading tiles of a particular area in osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am working on a project in which I need to download all tiles of a particular state for later offline usage.Can somebody help me with an example how to do that?I have all the postcodes of a particular state available with me

Comment: One possible solution is https://openmaptiles.org/ Also, your question is offtopic for StackOverflow. Try http://gis.stackexchange.com/ or http://help.openstreetmap.org/ next time.

Comment: thanks.let me try.will inform you